# Dual Monitor via HDMI, second screen only shows the background on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an HP Pavilion G6 (with Radeon Graphics) running Ubuntu 18.04. I have connected an LG monitor via the HDMI port.

On the monitor I just see the background of the laptop screen, with no icons or mouse movement, just the static background.

I have tried installing `gnome-tweaks` and enabled the option *Workspaces span across displays*.

I have also tried the same via `dconf-editor`:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/workspaces-only-on-primary false
$ dconf write /org/gnome/shell/overrides/workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

but nothing works.

Comment: OK. Trying `gnome-control-center`

Answer (score 0):

OK. So this solved my issue:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
$ gnome-control-center &
```

Go to *Devices* → *Displays* → *Display mode* and choose the display mode you like.